# Java / Android: LinkedList race condition

Tags: java, android, linked-list, synchronized

I am using a `LinkedList` in an android application, where I encounter race conditions. 1 thread adds data to the `LinkedList` while another removes them when they are retrieved. I encountered the siuation where my newly added objects are never handled.

I Googled for Java synchronized objects, but either I am thinking too easy or I am missing something. From what I've read "Object synchronization" is the more difficult of the two, so I was wondering if just enclosing a piece of code with `sychronized(object) { };` is enough?

So, I have:

```
public void function addMove(Object move) {
  synchronized(list) {
    list.add(move);
  };
};

public void function second() {
   synchronized(list) {
   // iterate through the list
   list.clear;
  };
};
```

Is this really all I need?

Comment: See java.util.Collections.synchronizedList.

Comment: why not just public void synchronized function() ?

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error? I am not familiar with the *function* word in the method declaration. You may just need `public void addMove(Object move) {...}` and `public void second() {...}`.

Comment: Why use `clear` instead of `remove` (perhaps delete)?

Comment: Because i had issues with remove() due to race conditions. If the LinkedList is altered during my iteration loop, the "location" that remove() needs changes. So that would cause the wrong item to be removed. Just clear()'ing the whole list works fine now that its synchronized.

Comment: @Phil: My code wasn't copy/pasted, it was "pseudo code". I am coding in both Java and PHP at the same time, thats why i Used "function". My bad :-) The code is not syntacticly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is properly encapsulated into your object (i.e. no other object has access to the list), and if these are the only methods accessing the list, then yes, this is all you need.

The key is that every access to the list must be done in a synchronized block. And every synchonized block must synchronize on the same object (`list`, in your code example).

Answer (score 3):

**-** In your case if your list is properly coupled with the Object and there is no other way to access it except this only method then i think that would be enough.

**-** Moreover the below approach can also be used:

```
public class Test{

 private LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();

 public void function addMove(Object move) {
  synchronized(this) {
    list.add(move);
  }
}

public void function second() {
   synchronized(this) {
   list.clear;
  }
 }


}
```

**//////////////////////////////////Edited Part///////////////////////**

**-** `Synchronization` is done to **protect the crucial state of data** and are **applied** on to the `method` or `atomic statements` accessing that `field` whose data is to be protected.

**-** `Every object` has **one and only one lock**, which is to be obtained by a `thread` to access the `synchronized` **methods** or **atomic statements** which has access to its `instance variables`.

**-** Similarly `every Class` has **one and only one lock**, which is to be obtained by a thread to access the `synchronized` **methods** or **atomic statements** which has access to its `static variable`.

**-** Now when an `thread` gains access over the lock of an object then after that it gets the access to its synchronized methods or atomic statements, and **if at that time another thread tries to access the same object lock**, then that **thread is denied** the access and it moves to the `blocked state`.

Comment: Thank you. What are the benefits of using this method instead of mine? And what exactly does it do? It synchronizes the whole class? Does that mean if 2 threads are accessing a variable in this class one of them has to wait? (Regardless if they access the same variable or not)

Comment: Nice answer! @user1750795, This ensures there is no `NullPointerException` with the `sychronized` Object, while providing a blocking solution.

Comment: @JBNizet as this synchronized block is based on the current object it won't be blocking all the instances... Each instance has its own instance variables copy.. I hope this is basic java

Comment: I commented when your code used Test.class as the lock, and not `this` as it does now.

Comment: @JBNizet please don't negate the answer until you are sure about what ur talking... i have changed Test.class with this just within 5 to 6 sec of giving my answer..i have no idea about it not getting updated....

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra: I can't read in your mind and know that you will fix an incorrect answer. When I commented, the answer was plain wrong, because it used Test.class as the lock. Now that you've fixed the answer, I removed the comment and the downvote. I don't know how I could be more gentle. If you don't want negative comments, don't post wrong answers. Your answer was wrong when I commented, and you shouldn't blame me for an error YOU made.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for removing the downvote, and please always refresh the answer by hitting the refresh option. There must be an update problem else there was no way anyone could see the Test.class as i have immediately changed it... well fine.... i will be more careful before posting it..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the way how you can control the access of threads for your object. All you have to do is to look on the timing of your methods. The clear command should only be called if there was data added to the list.

Comment: Why is that? Why can't I call clear() wheneven I want? If its already empty, nothing happends right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Android supports Java 5, but java.util.concurrent contains lots of excellent classes to support queues, such as ConcurrentLinkedQueue.